# memory allocation and reclaim in C++

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and just read some online tutorial about it. I am pretty curious about my experiment result in pointer. Here is my code:

```
int *p_value;
sizeof(*p_value) <--- I expected 0 but it shows 4
p_value = new int;
sizeof(*p_value) <--- it shows 8, make sense
delete(p_value)
sizeof(*p_value) <--- I expect 0, but it shows 4 again...
```

More importantly, I don't understand why does `p_value` point to the same memory address after delete operation. Is it necessary to be true?

---

Thanks for pointing out my misunderstanding over the operator "sizeof". But here is something I didn't state it too clear in my question.

here is another code:
    int *p_value = new int; 
    cout  << p_value <-- it prints the address of the new created int, say 0x000A;
    delete p_value;
    cout << p_value <-- it shows the same address before the "delete" called

Can i consider the "delete" just mark the 0x000A is not occupied in Map, I guess. But it won't change the content of the p_value?

Comment: Are you sure that you typed all the `sizeof()` the same way? To return 8 the second should be `sizeof(p_value)`.

Comment: @Bob__ is right, it seems an integer is 4 bytes in your machine. Thus the only way the second sizeof would return 8 is if it is the size of the pointer, which is an 8 byte adress

Comment: @Bob__ yes, i believe he mistyped the question, it probably was sizeof(p_value). I said you are right :)

Comment: @FábioJunqueira I belive you are right too ;) comment deleted

Comment: Yes... i mistype it... the sizeof() is going to return 8 instead of 4... Orz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key thing your missing is that `sizeof` is not a function. It doesn't look at the *value* of its argument at run time like a function does, just its *type* at compile time.

```
int *p_value;   
sizeof(*p_value) <--- I expected 0 but it shows 4
```

Since `p_value` is a pointer to an integer, `*p_value` is an integer. Integer are four bytes on your platform.

```
p_value = new int;   
sizeof(*p_value) <--- it shows 8, make sense
```

That's odd. Since `p_value` is a pointer to an integer, `*p_value` is an integer. So apparently, integers are 8 bytes on your platform.

```
delete(p_value)  
sizeof(*p_value) <--- I expect 0, but it shows 4 again...
```

Why do you expect 0? Since `p_value` is a pointer to an integer, `p_value` is an integer. So its size is 4 (or however many bytes an integer occupies on your platform). How else would `p_value = malloc (sizeof (*p_value));` work?

> more importantly, I don't understand why p_value point to the same memory address after delete operation. Is it necessary to be true?

Passing the value of a variable to a function doesn't change the value of that variable. So `delete (p_value)` doesn't change the value of `p_value`, except it now points to garbage.

Answer (score 3):

Your results cannot be true. All your cases output `size` of type `int` in `bytes` (and `sizeof(int)` cannot be changed due program run).

Answer (score 1):

All of the results returned by the above `sizeof(* ptr)` give you information about the size of the type it points to, **specific to your platform**, specifically the size of `int`, i.e. `4` means size: 4 bytes or 32 bits, thus the `int` can hold up to 2<sup>32 - 1-sign-bit</sup> different numbers.

You could think of the returned results as results from: `sizeof(int)`, which won't change regardless of the location* of your `int` of whether you free dynamically allocated memory, with `delete` or not, fact that, as @ForEveR, already said, makes your results dubious**.

---

*Static, stack or heap memory.

**Checked on two different platforms and the result is `4`, not `8`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *p_value;
sizeof(*p_value) <--- I expected 0 but it shows 4
```

`*p_value` is an integer, the size is typically 4 bytes, thus it shows 4. This does depends on the compiler too (C++ standard only mentioned that it should be at least 4 bytes). My test returns 8 though.

```
p_value = new int;
sizeof(*p_value) <--- it shows 8, make sense
```

If the above shows 4, then this one should shows 4 as well (unless you're using different compiler/target arch). The sizeof operator shows the number of bytes taken by the data type. The value itself is irrevalent.

```
delete(p_value)
sizeof(*p_value) <--- I expect 0, but it shows 4 again...
```

The same as above.